# Why the equipotential surface of a uniform electric field can't intersect itself?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

Why the equipotential surface of a uniform electric field can't intersect itself?

Comment: First I've found the question in the VtC queue. I tried to fix the question title, but I don't have any idea what could I post into the body. This resulted the question to be automatically inserted (by length & content) into the VLQ queue. Anybody having a better idea, how to fix it? Checking the answers, I think it is clear that it is an ontopic question.

Comment: @peterh At a minimum, you could repeat the question title in the body, though of course it is better to expand on it if you can do so without going beyond the OP's intent. One of my guidelines for writing good questions is that, hypothetically, if you could _only_ see the body of the question, not the title or tags, it should still make sense.

Comment: @DavidZ Ok, done.

Answer (score 3):

An equipotential surface has the same potential everywhere. If it should intersect another equipotential surface, then the intersection points would have both the potential of one and that of the other at the same time? Not possible. Ergo, they do not intersect.

Apart from that, your question is not clear to me regarding the normal you mention.